# Terraria Mobile - Valentine Ring?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I was playing Terraria on my mobile device, when I came across an item called the Valentine Ring. I purchased it, thinking it did something cool (the tooltip wasn't being displayed for some reason), but I can't figure out what it does. Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: This question is outdated due to the Terraria 1.13 mobile update.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki there is no item called the Valentine Heart. But if it were it'd be added in [the Valentine update](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Valentine_Update).

Maybe you mean the [Broken Heart Crystal?](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Broken_Heart_Crystal). It summons a cupid pet, which is pretty much the same as the Wisp in a Bottle, i.e., a moveable light source.

It's probably not a [Heart Arrow](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_Arrow) (which stuns enemies) or the [Valentine Ring](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Valentine_Ring) (which gives you extra jump height and 50% health regen if it were given to you by another person). Those two items are the others added during the Valentine Update.

If it is called a Valentine Heart I'd love a screenshot to find out more =p

Comment: Sorry, it was the Valentine Ring. Editing my post to say this.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping it on the ground and picking it up again should activate
The powers mentioned by Kevin van der velden, according to the wiki.

-edit-

To drop an item in pocket edition, drag the item to the ground from your hotbar
while your inventory is closed.

Comment: How would I do so?

Comment: Um... I don't actually know. That's all the wiki said

Comment: ._____________.

Comment: Press and hold on it while its in your hotbar (with your inventory closed) and drag it to where you want to drop it. Your character will throw it in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put it into a chest and then take it out, r you could drop it then pick it up.
It gives a 50% increased jump height and an increased health regeneration. The helpful tooltip will show after you activate it by doing what I mentioned above.
This website might help: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Valentine_Ring